# While doing a migrate how is the description in the schema_version table created

Tags: flyway

I am just getting into Flyway for our SQL Server database.  So far, everything is straight forward.

However, I can't seem to find a setting for the *migrate* command that will put a useful comment in the `schema_version.description` column.  Granted, all I have done is a few minor migrations just to test out, but I can't seem to find any setting to create this.  Is there one?  Is it pulled from the comments of a script?

Answer (score 0):

The migration description is taken from the name of your migration file. eg

`V1__this_will_be_your_description.sql`

The resulting description will have the version prefix, version and file suffix trimmed as well as underscores replace with spaces. So the resulting description for the above would be

`this will be your description`

See [`MigrationInfoHelper`](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/86dd8658fcc08b1c8c705aa7986d2f382b32e9d2/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/resolver/MigrationInfoHelper.java) if you are interested in the details.

To the best of my knowledge there is no other way to influence the description.

See the [documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/sql).